# Spring JPA Join two tables without third class

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Is there a way to join two tables in Spring JPA without using association class.

I have two MySQL DB tables :
employees(id,.....,department_id)
departments(id,.....)
And I'm searching for a way to join these tables using only my employee and department classes.

Currently, I managed to join two tables but with the third association class. 
My current implementation is:

**Employee class:**

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "employees")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "hire_date")
    private Double hireDate;

    @Column(name = "job_id")
    private Long jobId;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Double salary;

    @Column(name = "commission_pct")
    private Double commissionPct;

    @Column(name = "employees")
    private Long employees;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Department department;

}
```

**Department class:**

```
@Entity(name = "Department")
@Table(name = "departments")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Department implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "department_name")
    private String departmentName;

    @Column(name = "department_id")
    private long departmentId;

    @Column(name = "manager_id")
    private Double managerId;
    @Column(name = "location_id")
    private Double locationId;


}
```

**Association class:**

```
public class DeptEmpDto {
    private long departmentId;
    private String departmentName;
    private Double managerId;
    private Double locationId;
    private long employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Double hireDate;
    private Long jobId;
    private Double salary;
    private Double commissionPct;

}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.concretepage.entity.DeptEmpDto(d.departmentId,d.departmentName,d.managerId,d.locationId,e.employeeId,e.firstName,e.lastName,e.phoneNumber,e.hireDate,e.jobId,e.salary,e.commissionPct FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Department d ON d.id = e.jobId")
    List<DeptEmpDto> fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Query to join two table using Jparepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636720/hibernate-query-to-join-two-table-using-jparepository)

Comment: What do you mean by 'association class'? You have already joined the tables via `@ManyToOne`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in Employee class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "DeptEmp",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dep_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<Departments> departments = new HashSet<>();
```

[Look at this about JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many)

Comment: i`m searching a way to do it in repository class and only to use employee class .
For example to use something like this :
@Query("SELECT new com.concretepage.entity.Employee(employeeId,firstName,lastName,salary) FROM Employee")
but to add department fields too

Comment: When you use my option you will add a new filed to your class Employee. After that your ORM will update your class in database. After that you can get department by select Employee

Answer (score 0):

Logically an employee can't work in two departements so your relationship is correct

But you can do that with a `@ManyToMany` annotation.